# Is it possible to connect my website that is on the internet to my local SQL Server database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssh-tunnel, sql-server-2014-express

I'm trying to make a desktop app and website that shares the same database using SQL Server 2014 Enterprise. Is this possible? If so, how do i implement this?

UPDATE - i have considered to host my website on my own server. But i still can access my website through the internet provided that all requirements have been acquired.

-> obtain a static IP from the ISP
-> configured port-forwarding from the modem to the router and router to the server-unit

Comment: *Possible* - yes, with a bit of effort. But even if it's *possible*, that doesn't mean it 's a *good idea* to expose your local SQL Server as a public resource on the internet......

Comment: If so, how do i implement this?

Comment: Express or Enterprise.

Comment: A better approach might be to host the website and database on the internet, and also have a web API layer which both the desktop app and website can call to access business logic and database functions which are required by both apps. Only the API would access the database directly. That way a) you can re-use some functionality shared between both applications and  b) you don't have to run the risk of exposing your database directly to the internet. What I've described is a pretty common and conventional architecture for this kind of situation

Comment: Thank you i got the gist of it! Time to do research on how to do it..

Comment: It is Enterprise version

Comment: how do i make my web and desktop app call this web api layer. And where do i put this api, supposed to be with the web server right?, my problem is i cant connect to the sql server with a connection string connecting to my public ip. and i already configured the port forwarding along with the sql browser and sql server respective ports. my public ip is Dynamic so i have to consider the DDNS configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure port forwarding on your router and DDNS if you don't have a static public IP address.

Comment: I have tried the port forwarding. But, i dont know about that DDNS stuff. How do i configure my DDNS?

Comment: It depends what router you have. For example https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1011725/ here you have solution for ASUS. Btw you can configure DDNS on NAS also. Let it be clear - without DDNS it should work also but you have to watch if IP address was changed and modify your connection string